# Scala method overload for a special case of a generic type

Tags: scala

I have the following methods:

```
def foo[A](x: =>A) = ???

def foo[B](x: =>WrapperType[B]) = ???
```

This does not compile, and it makes sense because, in the first method, A could also stand for `WrapperType[B]`. I could check the type of `x` at runtime, but it seems that there ought to be a way of doing this at compile time. How can I overcome this problem?

**Note**: the code above is a simplification of my real code, which is:

```
def ifEmpty[B](errors:Seq[Error]*)(right: =>B): Either[Seq[Error], B] =
  if( areAllEmpty(errors) ) Right(right)
  else                      Left(errors.flatten)

def ifEmpty[C](errors:Seq[Error]*)(right: =>Either[Seq[Error], C]): Either[Seq[Error], C] =
  if( areAllEmpty(errors) ) right
  else                      Left(errors.flatten)
```

Comment: It's interesting that this works without the lazy `=>` before the types

Comment: read about magnet pattern http://spray.io/blog/2012-12-13-the-magnet-pattern/  I guess this can help you to overcome overloading problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the usual method (hack) to disambiguate the signatures:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object Y {
def f[A](a: =>  A) = 1
def f[A](a: => Either[Exception, A])(implicit d: DummyImplicit) = 2
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined object Y

scala> Y.f(42)
res0: Int = 1

scala> Y.f(Right(42))
res1: Int = 2
```

Your `foo`s erase to the same signature because the params are turned into functions under the hood.

To Scala, though, `foo(Wrapper)` is more specific than `foo(A)`.

Your sample real code cannot work because it is a double definition: overloading only considers the first parameter list.

Edit: Don't test it [this way.](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9170)

Answer (score 2):

There is a way but it involves some type hackery and potentially locating your logic in a place away from your method invocation:

```
def foo[A](f: => A)(implicit switch: Switch[A]) = switch(f)
```

and with this, you can now switch logic on the type of the return of the variable `f`.

```
trait Switch[A]{
  def apply(f: => A): Whatever
}

object Switch extends LowPrioritySwitch{
  def apply[A](implicit switch: Switch[A]) = switch

  implicit def wrapped[B] = new Switch[WrappedArray[B]]{
    def apply(f: => WrappedArray[B]) = ...
  }
}

trait LowPrioritySwitch{
  implicit def any[A] = new Switch[A]{
    def apply(f: => A) = ...
  }
}
```

And all this is to take advantage of implicit resolution order. That is, the compiler will attempt to match the first implicit in the object definition before attempting to match the next implicit found within the trait. Hence the name.

Comment: The LowPriority trait is not required, since `Switch[Option[B]]` is already more specific than `Switch[A]`. Further: https://github.com/NICTA/scoobi/pull/324

Comment: Actually if you place them both at the same "level" then you'll get an ambiguous implicit. Scala doesn't map to the most specific type, it maps to the implicit that is of higher priority which first matches.

Comment: "If there are several eligible arguments which match the implicit parameter's type, a most specific one will be chosen using the rules of static overloading resolution." http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/07-implicit-parameters-and-views.html

Comment: See if we're talking about the same thing: https://gist.github.com/som-snytt/78637c27d7737106a586

Comment: The notion of "level" derives from static overloading, where you get a point of weight when defined in a derived class.

Comment: @som-snytt interesting. Thanks! I had been so used to implicit ambiguity that I have been doing this "wrong," i.e. needlessly verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to solve it, borrowing an idea from each answer:

```
def ifEmpty[A](errors:Seq[Error]*)(implicit magnet:IfEmptyMagnet[A]): Either[Seq[Error], A] = magnet(errors:_*)

trait IfEmptyMagnet[+A] {
  def areAllEmpty(seqs: Seq[Any]*) = seqs.forall(_.size == 0)
  def apply(errors:Seq[Error]*): Either[Seq[Error], A]
}

implicit def ifEmptyMagnet[A](a: =>  A) = new IfEmptyMagnet[A]{
  def apply(errors:Seq[Error]*): Either[Seq[Error], A] = {
    if( areAllEmpty(errors) ) Right(a)
    else                      Left(errors.flatten)
  }
}

implicit def ifEmptyMagnet[A](a: => Either[Seq[Error], A])(implicit d: DummyImplicit) = new IfEmptyMagnet[A]{
  def apply(errors:Seq[Error]*): Either[Seq[Error], A] = {
    if( areAllEmpty(errors) ) a
    else                      Left(errors.flatten)
  }
}
```

Comment: `magnet` itself need not be implicit; the implicit defs go in `object IfEmptyMagnet`. If you own the wrapper class, you could put the second implicit in its companion and lose the Dummy. Suggest prefer `_.isEmpty` to `_.size == 0`.